# No column name was specified for column 1 of 'd'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, join

I am trying to get some data from 3 tables in SQL Server, but getting an error.

I have created a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c6890fb9409f3a8ca9ddf52fa57debed) with similar structure and sample data

Based on the data in tblData, I am trying to get the table id, along with a concatenated string of the column names.

```
id     colNames
1005   City, Name, State, EmpId
1006   City, State, Name, EmpId
1008   City, Name, EmpId, Phone, State
1009   City, Name, Phone, EmpId
```

What could be the issue with this query?

```
select tp.id tmpltID,
        stuff(( select distinct d.colName from (SELECT colOrder,
        t.Name as colName
        FROM [dbo].[tblProj] pd
         join [dbo].[tblTemp] t on pd.tblName = t.tblname
        join tblData dt on t.id=dt.tmpId
        ORDER BY colOrder 
        FOR XML PATH('')) d
        )  ,
         1,
         1,
         '') 
         from [tblTemp] tp
         GROUP BY tp.id;
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'd'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'colName'.
```

If I don't use `distinct`, the column names get repeated as a tmpId could be present multiple times in `tblData`.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to join to `tblTemp` again in your sub-query. You can use `APPLY` operator to make your query more readable.

```
SELECT tp.id as tmpltID,
       STUFF ( pd.Name, 1, 2, '' )  as colNames
FROM   [tblTemp] tp
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           SELECT ', ' + pd.Name
           FROM  [dbo].[tblProj] pd
           WHERE pd.tblName = tp.tblName
           ORDER BY pd.colOrder 
           FOR XML PATH ('')
       ) pd (Name)
WHERE  pd.Name IS NOT NULL
```